# Is there an equivalent register to Intel's MSR_SMI_COUNT on AMD architecture?

Tags: x86-64, hardware, amd-processor

On recent Intel CPUs it's possible to count the number of SMIs that have occurred, by reading msr 0x34.

I have checked the manuals at -
https://developer.amd.com/resources/developer-guides-manuals/

for an equivalent register/function, without success.

Answer (score 2):

AMD Zen specifies the LsSmiRx performance counter for [System Management Interrupts (SMIs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode):

> ```
> PMCx02B [SMIs Received] (Core::X86::Pmc::Core::LsSmiRx)
> Counts the number of SMIs received.
> ```

([Open-Source
Register Reference
For AMD Family 17h Processors
Models 00h-2Fh. Rev 3.03, 2018, page 153](https://developer.amd.com/wp-content/resources/56255_3_03.PDF))

On Linux, you can monitor it like this:

```
# perf stat -e ls_smi_rx -I 60000
```

This command prints each minute a count of all newly triggered SMIs aggregated over all CPUs.

---

That means for monitoring - unlike with the `MSR_SMI_COUNT` register available on Intel CPUs - you have to actively program a PMU register (to observe the LsSmiRx event).

---

NB: The above referenced AMD documentation confirms that AMD Zen doesn't support the SMI_COUNT MSR (0x34), since it isn't included in the list of  available MSRs (in Chapter 2.1.10, page 77).

Answer (score 1):

No, but SMI count is available as a PMC (performance counter) on AMD processors.