# Obtaining SMI_COUNT on amd cpu

Tags: x86-64, inline-assembly, amd-processor

I am trying to get familiar with AMD's interface of SMM. Want to implement simple task:

1. Check SMI_COUNT
2. Trigger SMI
3. Check SMI_COUNT after trigger

The SMI-interrupt is a rare thing (I believe), so SMI_COUNT on step 3 should should be +1 from that obtained on step 1. The problem for me is to get the value of SMI_COUNT on my AMD-processor(architecture amd64).

By reading this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055831/is-there-an-equivalent-register-to-intels-msr-smi-count-on-amd-architecture) we notice that SMI_COUNT could be obtained on AMD64-architecture by reading "Performance-Counter-Register" with instruction `rdpmc`.

[AMD manual vol. 3](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24594.pdf) teaches us about `RDPMC`

> Reads the contents of a 64-bit performance counter and returns it in the registers EDX:EAX. The
> ECX register is used to specify the **index** of the performance counter to be read. The EDX
> register receives the high-order 32 bits and the EAX register receives the low order 32 bits of
> the counter. The RDPMC instruction ignores operand size; the index and the return values are all > 32 bits.

The thing I don't understand is what is the "index" that is placed into ECX. Could not find any clarification on that. By reading another [AMD manual](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/56255_OSRR.pdf) we find on page 153:

```
PMCx02B [SMIs Received] (Core::X86::Pmc::Core::LsSmiRx)
Counts the number of SMIs received.
```

So probably for SMI_COUNT I should supply the `ECX:=0x2b` which does not work (you'll see later).

I've built the kernel module which does the following to obtain the value of any PerformaceCounter-Register based on "index":

```
uint64_t get_pcr_value(uint32_t pcr_idx) {
    uint32_t highpc = 0;
    uint32_t lowpc = 0;

    asm volatile (
        "rdpmc\n\t"
        : "=d"(highpc), "=a"(lowpc)
        : "c"(pcr_idx)
        :
    );
    return ((uint64_t)highpc << 32) + lowpc;
}
```

Then I do `pcr_idx:=0x2b` to get the SMI_COUNT

```
smi_count_before = get_pcr_value(0x2b);
out(0xb2); // triggers smi, just believe me here
smi_count_after = get_pcr_value(0x2b);
```

It returs `smi_count_before=0xffff2d3a1f83, smi_count_after=0xffff2d3a7ce6` which is a too crazy delta between smi counts. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Intel](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdpmc)'s docs might shed (a bit) more light, but they're not completely clear here either.

Comment: `rdpmc` only read a PM Counter but a PMC must first be configured to count something. One of the `Core::X86::Msr::PERF_CTL` MSRs must be used to count the event `0x2b` (by setting the `EventSelect` and other relevant fields), then you can read the counting in the associated `Core::X86::Msr::PERF_CTR` or using `rdpmc` with the index of that `PERF_CTR`. As standing, you are reading the counter `0x2b` which surely doesn't exist (the manual you linked shows only 11 counters).